# Is there a way to avoid copying the buffer passed to cairo-rs?

Tags: memory, rust

I'm using cairo-rs, and I need to create an ImageSurface from an ARGB buffer (a `Vec<u8>`). Here's the function from cairo-rs I'm calling:

```rust
pub fn create_for_data<D: AsMut<[u8]> + 'static>(
        data: D,
        format: Format,
        width: i32,
        height: i32,
        stride: i32,
    ) -> Result<ImageSurface, Error> {
        let mut data: Box<dyn AsMut<[u8]>> = Box::new(data);

        let (ptr, len) = {
            let data: &mut [u8] = (*data).as_mut();

            (data.as_mut_ptr(), data.len())
        };

        // omitted: pass ptr to the underlying C API
```

So I'm passing my `Vec<u8>` to this function and it works because `Vec<u8>` is `AsMut<[u8]>`, but I'm curious how it exactly works. Am I actually copying the whole buffer and then immediately boxing it again? If so, is there a way to avoid copying and reallocating the buffer, given this API (which I cannot change)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not copying the buffer just the `Vec` (ie the pointer, length and capacity) and quite needlessly, you can just call `.as_mut()` on `data` directly:

```rust
pub fn create_for_data<D: AsMut<[u8]>>(mut data: D) {
    let (ptr, len) = {
        let data = data.as_mut();

        (data.as_mut_ptr(), data.len())
    };
    //…
}
```

Comment: `create_for_data` is not my function, but an API from external crate that I'm calling, I just looked up its source code. But now I see that we'll just end up having a `Box<Vec<u8>>`. Thanks